# Height of the body part of my layout

Tags: html, css

I need a height problem looked at...

Here is a link to my page:
http://www.whiterootmedia.com/database/test/relative.html

If you zoom all the way out, the `#article` div background will not go to the footer. How do I make the `#article`'s height 100% minus the banner, nav, and footer given that the nav div will be a dynamic height.

I was trying to `position:absolute` the footer, but I don't think I can do the same to the banner and nav divs.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/). It works cross browser and doesn't need any javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can try min-height in CSS, is it important to scroll out ?

and don´t position it absolute !